# Is Geoenrichment a trademarked Esri term?

Tags: arcgis-online, legal, geoenrichment

I've recently seen the term "[Geoenrichment](https://geoenrichdev.arcgis.com/arcgis/)" turning up on ArcGIS Online.  Is this a term Esri invented, or are other organizations using this terminology? Are there other synonyms for Geoenrichment?  Does Esri have a trademark on this term?

Comment: I might register _geo-embiggen™_

Comment: I see nowhere online where it's claimed as a registered trademark, but I'd avoid poking the bear and assume it's a trademark/servicemark. Same thing as the generic/specific terms autocomplete and IntelliSense, I'd look to invent a generic term like "spatially enable" or "spatially extend" just to avoid any phone calls from lawyers in Redlands.

Comment: It's also not in [TESS](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=searchss&state=4803:qj1lje.1.1), the US trademark electronic search system.

Comment: I note that the term is used outside of a local interest context, to do with the concentration of heavy metals such as Arsenic and Lead in soils.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Esri page on [Copyrights and Trademarks](http://www.esri.com/legal/copyright-trademarks) does not currently mention Geoenrichment but to me that may mean that the page is just due for an update.

The same page offers an [email option](http://www.esri.com/apps/company/copyright/mail-copyright.cfm) for any questions about its content.

Comment: A custom time range Google search shows that Yahoo used the term in 2007 and Esri also was using it in 2008. This was not an exhaustive search, but highlights that it's not a recent term.